# Linking Multiple Minecraft Worlds Together

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Is there a way for me to be able to access one world from another using Minecraft Forge 1.10.2? (Not Bukkit)

If there isn't, is there a way for me to run Bukkit plugins in Minecraft Forge?

Comment: Are you trying to use the same character on multiple worlds, like in Terraria?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I came up with a way to do it on a server using BungeeCord. However, it needs multiple Minecraft servers to run at once.

The best way I came up with to run plugins with Forge is to use Sponge. However, it doesn't work with normal Bukkit/Spigot plugins.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, no. There are probably not any mods that can do this, and you cannot run bukkit plugins with forge.

But you can get bukkit plugins for a bukkit server (which are pretty easy to make) That can do the job.

You can download a craftbukkit server from here: https://getbukkit.org/craftbukkit

although if you haven't made an mc server before, you will probably have to do the port forwarding in which case you can watch a youtube video and there are some pretty helpful tutorials on the subject.

Though if you do not want to go to the trouble, then there is no other way as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

**Untested!** If you use a filesystem which supports symbolic links (i.e. Mac or Linux, not Windows) you should be able to link the End dimension of the two worlds. This means that the seperate worlds will share the same End. Since you're playing with mods, you don't have to use the End, you could use a mod like MystCraft, Aether or the one with dimlets and dialling (forgot what it's called, sorry) to create more dimensions, and link one of those.

"Why can't I link the Nether instead of the End? It will be a lot easier to access."
You could. But because of the way that nether portals work, you'll have a hard time. Much safer to use the End or a modded dimension.

True, you don't get to access the entire world from the other. But this is the best alternative that I can think of.